# Remove question marks between these two tags

Tags: php, regex

I have, for example, this string:

```
asd? asdfasdfsdf <description>&lt;div? style=&quot;color:000000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, ?sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-size:12px;width:555px;&quot;&gt;Bohus Malm?t;/a&gt;</description> blah blah blah? asdfasfize:12px;font-size:?
```

I need to know how I can remove all the ? that exists only between the opening and closing "description" tags, but not the ones outside it.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using this for? Will it always be the 'description' tag?

Comment: Yes, it will always be in the description tag.  I need to remove the question marks within these tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'asd? asdfasdfsdf <description>&lt;div? style=&quot;color:000000;font-' . 
       'family:Arial, Helvetica, ?sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-size:12px;' . 
       'width:555px;&quot;&gt;Bohus Malm?t;/a&gt;</description> blah blah ' . 
       'blah? asdfasfize:12px;font-size:?';  
function myReplace($matches)  
{  
    return $matches[1].str_replace('?', '', $matches[2]).$matches[3];  
}  
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '|(.*<description>)(.*)(<\/description>.*)|', 
    'myReplace', 
    $str
);  
echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

Comment: What if `<!-- <description> -->` is present? Or `<script>var s = "</description>";</script>`

Comment: From the given string, it looks like the inner and outer content are escaped. Of course, no regex will be as complete as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), especially when even it's fallible.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$var = 'asd? asdfasdfsdf <description>&lt;div? style=&quot;color:000000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, ?sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-size:12px;width:555px;&quot;&gt;Bohus Malm?t;/a&gt;</description> blah blah blah? asdfasfize:12px;font-size:?';
preg_match( '/(.*)(<description>.*<\/description>)(.*)/', $var, $matches );
$new = $matches[1] . str_replace( '?', '', $matches[2] ) . $matches[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'asd? asdfasdfsdf <description>&lt;div? style=&quot;color:000000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, ?sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-size:12px;width:555px;&quot;&gt;Bohus Malm?t;/a&gt;</description> blah blah blah? asdfasfize:12px;font-size:?';
$regex = '/(<description>.*)\?(.*<\/description>)/i';

while (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
     $string = preg_replace($regex, '$1$2', $string);
}
echo $string; 
?>
```